# c# reflection for input string validation

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am new to C#. have a few doubts about using reflection for input string validation. I have this code:

```
var properties = inputStr.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in properties)
{
    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType)??prop.PropertyType;

    if(type==typeof(char)
    {
      char charTxt ='a';
      var charVal = prop.GetValue(inputStr,new Object[] {0});
      if(charVal == null)
        continue;
      if(char.TryParse(prop.GetValue(inputStr,new Object[] {0}).ToString()), out charTxt))
      {
      }
      else{
        return "invalid"
    }
}
```

Here we pass string value as input and get properties of the string. it's actually Char and Int. So for Char property , in the line

```
var charVal = prop.GetValue(inputStr,new Object[] {0});
```

I want know what exactly they are doing, are they trying to get the Char property value from object (input str) and validating if that is null?

and in the TryParse line

```
if(char.TryParse(prop.GetValue(inputStr,new Object[] {0}).ToString()), out charTxt))
```

I'm getting only 1st character of the string using `GetValue(inputStr,new Object[] {0})` . how can i get the complete string instead of getting characters one by one using GetValue()?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @jazb I've clarified it as best I can see

Comment: @Lavan if you terminate question sentences with a ? it makes it more obvious they're a question

Comment: If you have this condition " if(type==typeof(char)" that means your property is char type. So yes, it will return only one char, what do u expect? Beside your code doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. I want to know what is the way to validate the input string using reflection

Comment: I am in the beginning stage of .net. if someone explains this line prop.GetValue(inputStr), it would be better.

Comment: What is your actual goal? The idea of using reflection for input validation seem miss guided. The type system will ensure that the object is an actual string (or null) with all the properties of said string. So if you want the property values, why not just access the properties?

Comment: Also, if you are new to .net and programming in general, I would stay away from reflection. It can be useful as a last resort, but in the vast majority of cases there are simpler and better way  to do things.

Comment: Reflection definitely has its uses, but I can't see why you'd need it to validate a string. Most validation use cases can be satisfied using the methods of the [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0) class, and if you need something more powerful than that then try the [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) class and [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: got it. thank you all for your responses. i go with normal validation for input string